# How to verify secp256k1 signature inside app/business instruction?

Tags: anchor, solana-program, cpi, signature

I only find one document: [secp256k1_instruction](https://docs.rs/solana-sdk/latest/solana_sdk/secp256k1_instruction/index.html). It create two instructions, first one is to call secp256k1_program to verify, second one check the result of first instruction. But this way isn't what I want. Also, it seem too complicated.

I want to verify a signature inside on-chain program, just with one instruction.
That is, business logic and verification all done inside one instruction.

What I suppose is to pass { msg, signature} via instruction arguemnt AND check recovered pubkey agaist the sign Pubkey that saved to program ahead of verifying action, if success, then continue do business logic. Can I use  { msg, signature} to build instruction and data in my on-chain program
and then use CPI to call secp256k1_program to verify ?

Can anyone guide me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `secp256k1_recover` syscall from your program, as shown in this example program: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/master/programs/sbf/rust/secp256k1_recover/src/lib.rs

Copying from the example -- you'll need to use your own values for the signature, pubkey and hash:

```
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn entrypoint(_input: *mut u8) -> u64 {
    let expected: [u8; 64] = [
        0x42, 0xcd, 0x27, 0xe4, 0x0f, 0xdf, 0x7c, 0x97, 0x0a, 0xa2, 0xca, 0x0b, 0x88, 0x5b, 0x96,
        0x0f, 0x8b, 0x62, 0x8a, 0x41, 0xa1, 0x81, 0xe7, 0xe6, 0x8e, 0x03, 0xea, 0x0b, 0x84, 0x20,
        0x58, 0x9b, 0x32, 0x06, 0xbd, 0x66, 0x2f, 0x75, 0x65, 0xd6, 0x9d, 0xbd, 0x1d, 0x34, 0x29,
        0x6a, 0xd9, 0x35, 0x38, 0xed, 0x86, 0x9e, 0x99, 0x20, 0x43, 0xc3, 0xeb, 0xad, 0x65, 0x50,
        0xa0, 0x11, 0x6e, 0x5d,
    ];

    let hash: [u8; 32] = [
        0xde, 0xa5, 0x66, 0xb6, 0x94, 0x3b, 0xe0, 0xe9, 0x62, 0x53, 0xc2, 0x21, 0x5b, 0x1b, 0xac,
        0x69, 0xe7, 0xa8, 0x1e, 0xdb, 0x41, 0xc5, 0x02, 0x8b, 0x4f, 0x5c, 0x45, 0xc5, 0x3b, 0x49,
        0x54, 0xd0,
    ];
    let recovery_id: u8 = 1;
    let signature: [u8; 64] = [
        0x97, 0xa4, 0xee, 0x31, 0xfe, 0x82, 0x65, 0x72, 0x9f, 0x4a, 0xa6, 0x7d, 0x24, 0xd4, 0xa7,
        0x27, 0xf8, 0xc3, 0x15, 0xa4, 0xc8, 0xf9, 0x80, 0xeb, 0x4c, 0x4d, 0x4a, 0xfa, 0x6e, 0xc9,
        0x42, 0x41, 0x5d, 0x10, 0xd9, 0xc2, 0x8a, 0x90, 0xe9, 0x92, 0x9c, 0x52, 0x4b, 0x2c, 0xfb,
        0x65, 0xdf, 0xbc, 0xf6, 0x8c, 0xfd, 0x68, 0xdb, 0x17, 0xf9, 0x5d, 0x23, 0x5f, 0x96, 0xd8,
        0xf0, 0x72, 0x01, 0x2d,
    ];

    let public_key = solana_program::secp256k1_recover::secp256k1_recover(&hash[..], recovery_id, &signature[..]).unwrap();
    assert_eq!(public_key.to_bytes(), expected);
    
    0
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your answer is informative, could be one of the choice.
I am now using `two-instruction` approach from this demo: https://github.com/GuidoDipietro/solana-ed25519-secp256k1-sig-verification